# Local diffeomorphism everywhere vs. global diffeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

If I understood it correctly, there could theoretically exist a function (map) that is a diffeomorphism (i.e. bijective, continuously differentiable and with continuous differentiable inverse) locally *everywhere* (i.e. in a neighborhood of every point where it is defined), but still not a global diffeomorphism.
However, I cannot come up with an example. Could someone help me?

Comment: Smooth covering maps provide examples that you're looking for, eg $z\mapsto z^2$ on the unit circle.

Comment: Every non-bijective smooth function whose differential is everywhere an isomorphism does the job. (Unramified) smooth coverings of degree $\geq 2$ are the classical example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_diffeomorphism

Comment: I don't think you need to say "everywhere".  Local diffeomorphism will suffice.   "Everywhere" is implicit.

Answer (score 3):

Smooth covering maps provide examples of local diffeomorphisms that are not bijections. One simple class of examples are self-covers of the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ given by $z\mapsto z^n$ ($n$ an integer).